# how can I select all descendants of a certain element with ElementTree in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

This is the sample data.

input.xml

```
<root>
    <entry id="1">
    <headword>go</headword>
    <example>I <hw>go</hw> to school.</example>
</entry>
</root>
```

I'd like to put  node and its descendants into . That is,

output.xml

```
<root>
    <entry id="1">
    <headword>go</headword>
            <examplegrp>
                <example>I <hw>go</hw> to school.</example>
            </examplegrp>
</entry>
</root>
```

My poor and incomplete script is:

```
import codecs
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fin = codecs.open(r'input.xml', 'rb', encoding='utf-8')

data = ET.parse(fin)
root = data.getroot()

example = root.find('.//example')
for elem in example.iter():
    ---and then I don't know what to do---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how it can be done:

```
text = """
<root>
    <entry id="1">
        <headword>go</headword>
        <example>I <hw>go</hw> to school.</example>
    </entry>
</root>
"""

import lxml.etree
import StringIO

data = lxml.etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(text))
root = data.getroot()

for entry in root.xpath('//example/ancestor::entry[1]'):
    examplegrp = lxml.etree.SubElement(entry,"examplegrp")
    nodes = [node for node in entry.xpath('./example')]
    for node in nodes:
        entry.remove(node)
        examplegrp.append(node)

print lxml.etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True)
```

which will output:

```
<root>
    <entry id="1">
        <headword>go</headword>
        <examplegrp><example>I <hw>go</hw> to school.</example>
    </examplegrp></entry>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=xml#node-objects
http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=xml#document-objects

You probably want to follow some paradigm of creating a Document Element and appending reach result to it.

```
group = Document.createElement(tagName)
for found in founds:
    group.appendNode(found)
```

Or something like this